# colon or dash? punctuation

Tags: punctuation, dashes, colons

Please suggest the correct punctuation at points 1, 2 and 3 in the following sentence:

> If you had to write an article, for example, reporting on events in
>   any institution which cares for people **(1)** a borstal, a hospital, a
>   mental health institution, a nursing home, or even a prison **(2)** anywhere
>   where people look after, or guard, or care for **(3)** you might well head
>   it "My brother's keeper".

Particularly I'd like to know which punctuation mark I should use in (1) - colon or dash? - and why.
For anyone interested in the context of this sentence - it's an excerpt from the speech given by a professor about the King James Bible and its influence on the English language. https://youtu.be/lgSDd6Bkatg?t=1887

Comment: The sentence doesn't work. I'll suggest one that does: <<  If you had to write an article, for example, reporting on events in any institution which cares for people  (a borstal, a hospital, a mental health institution, a nursing home, or even a prison  – in fact, anywhere where people monitor, or guard, or care for others)  you might well head it "My brother's keeper". >>

Comment: I'd really want to have em dashes in all three places indicated. But that of course looks unwieldy. One workaround would be to keep the em dash for each of 1 and 3, and then use a semicolon for the 2. And yes, as Edwin says there seems to be a word missing, but if that's what the speaker said, then that's what they said.

Comment: Using more than two dashes in a sentence is frowned upon.  If I were to stick to leaving it as one sentence and otherwise wording it exactly as written where possible, I'd write, "If you had to write an article, for example, reporting on events in any institution that cares for people (a borstal, a hospital, a mental health institution, a nursing home, or even a prison–anywhere where people are looked after, guarded, or cared for), you might well head it 'My Brother's Keeper.' "  The single quotes appear because I'm writing the sentence within double quotes, but you wouldn't do that.

Comment: Know your original phrasing "anywhere where people look after, or guard, or care for" is problematic. One, previously, you've said "institutions which care for people," so saying "people" as the subject here is confusing, especially as you don't attach the object "people" to any of the prepositions. Do you mean "anywhere where employees...care for people"? Two, when repeating the conjunction, don't use commas. It's either "look after, guard, or care for" or "look after or guard or care for." Three, the phrase is redundant. You already said "any institution which cares for people."

Comment: By the way, "that" is preferred over "which" when it's a restrictive clause (i.e., "in any institution *that* cares for people). In spoken English, the only way for listeners to discern whether what follows the pronoun restrictively modifies the preceding noun or non-restrictively modifies it is by the speaker using "that" when it restrictively does and "which" when it non-restrictively does. Here, you are restricting "any institution" to just include institutions caring for people.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I'm not the author. As I said in the first post, it's an excerpt from the speech given by a professor. If you want to hear the original you can open the link I mentioned in that post, it will lead you directly to the moment when this sentence was uttered.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman As for "that/which" issue, maybe he said "which" because he is a British person. I've read that they are less scrupulous in their usage of these pronouns than Americans.